# Species-ID: What is this thing attached to my wall (California, USA)

Tags: species-identification, zoology, entomology, lepidoptera

I found this thing attached to my wall next to my garden. I live in Simi Valley, California, USA.

At first I thought it was a caterpillar and I left it alone, but after 2 or 3 months I don’t think it is a caterpillar anymore. I touched it today for the first time and it moves. What is it?

[image]

Comment: What is the approximate size? Maybe 3cm?

Comment: It is About 1.5-2cm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is very likely a [chrysalis](http://www3.canisius.edu/~grandem/butterflylifecycle/The_Lifecycle_of_a_Butterfly_print.html) (or pupa) stage of a [lepidopteran](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lepidoptera).

A similar looking example belongs to the giant swallowtail butterfly ([*Papilio cresphontes*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papilio_cresphontes)).

[image]

<sup>Source: [Bill Frank](http://www.jaxshells.org/8134.htm)</sup>

*P. cresphontes* is found in southern California [[source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Papilio_cresphontes#Geographic_range)], so it would not be unreasonable to find it in Simi Valley.